# License to use Spring tools 4

Tags: spring-tools-4

What license is required to use Spring Tools 4? What is Spring Tools 4 licensed under? I have looked on the website but am unable to find a license (i.e. GNU, GPL, Apache, EULA). Does anyone know the correct license?

Answer (score 1):

They use the [Eclipse Public License - version 1.0](https://github.com/spring-projects/sts4/blob/master/license.txt). If you have more questions about the license and I can recommend [this website](https://www.eclipse.org/legal/eplfaq.php).